# Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference on line 14

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting the error `Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference on line 14`

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
$messaqage = '';

if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

    // Enter the new user in the database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password',password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

    if( $stmt->execute() ):
        $message = 'Successfully created new user';
    else:
        $message = 'Sorry there must be an issue creating your account';
    endif;

endif;

?>
```

I am stuck in resolving this error. I am not able to debug the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't consider this a question, it's a bunch of code being displayed here. Please add some explanation.

Comment: $password  = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_BCRYPT);  $stmt->bindParam(':password',$password);

Answer (score 0):

`bindParam()` second argument is a reference. You pass a function result. change like this .

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_BCRYPT); 
$stmt->bindParam(':password',$password);
```